# How to wait for all actions(success/failure after request) to dispatch in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I have following actions:

```
export function createRequest(inputValues) {
  return {
    type: actions.PERSON_CREATE_REQUEST,
    payload: {
      inputValues
    }
  };
}

export function createSuccess(person) {
  return {
    type: actions.PERSON_CREATE_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      person: person
    }
  };
}

export function createFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: actions.PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE,
    payload: {
      error
    }
  };
}
```

Saga:

```
export function* createPerson(action) {
  try {
    const data = yield call((async () => {
      const person = action.payload.inputValues;
      return await api.post(person);
    }));
     yield put(createSuccess(data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(createFailure(error));
  }
}


export function* watchCreatePerson() {
  yield takeEvery('PERSON_CREATE_REQUEST', createPerson);
}

export function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    fork(watchCreatePerson),
  ];
}
```

Function that is called on form submit:

```
handleSubmit = async (event, values) => {
    event.preventDefault();
      await store.dispatch(action.createRequest(values));
      if (this.props.error === null) {
        store.dispatch(reset(this.props.form));
      }
  };
```

After `await store.dispatch(action.createRequest(values));` I want to check if `PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE` or `PERSON_CREATE_SUCCESS` was dispatched. On `PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE` I set `error` in store that is mapped to props. But next line of code with `if` is called after `PERSON_CREATE_REQUEST` is dispatched. But I need to wait until `PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE` or `PERSON_CREATE_SUCCESS` dispatch. How to change saga to wait for that actions dispatches?

Answer (score 0):

In the `handleSubmit` function, just dispatch the `createRequest` action, don't await it's response at this point in your code.

Now, if the request fails, write a reducer to handle the `PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE` action. Within this reducer you can then set the application state appropriately i.e. reset the form state. Then using `MapStateToProps` for your component which encompasses your form, you form will automatically re-render to match the updated (and in this case reset) form state.

Note that with this approach you will need to create your form's state in the Redux store, but doing so will simplify the application's state lifecyle.

Comment: I use redux-form so it's connected to store. and I have MapStateToProps. The problem is the order. How it works now: PERSON_CREATE_REQUEST, my code with resetting form because error is not updated,PERSON_CREATE_SUCCESS/PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE. I want it to dispatch PERSON_CREATE_REQUEST and PERSON_CREATE_SUCCESS/PERSON_CREATE_FAILURE and after it code with form resetting when my error is updated.

Comment: The point I am making is I don't see a need for you to await the result of the createRequest action in your handleSubmit function. You can achieve the behaviour you want via your reducers and React.